# Solution Verifivation

Tags: proof-verification, definite-integrals

### Problem

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function, and
$$\int_0^x f(x-t){\rm d}t=e^{-2x}(x+1)-1.$$
Find $\int_0^1 f(x){\rm d}x$ and $f(x).$

### Solution

Differentiate the both sides of the assumption equality with respect to $x$. For
the left hand side, we make a substitution $x-t=:u$ and obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}\int_0^xf(x-t){\rm d}t&=\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}(u+t)}\int_x^0f(u){\rm d}(x-u)\\
&=\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}u}\int_0^xf(u){\rm d}u\\
&=f(x).
\end{align*}

As for the right hand side, we may directly obtain
$$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}[e^{-2x}(x+1)-1]=-e^{-2x}(2x+1).$$

Thus
$$f(x)=-e^{-2x}(2x+1),$$
$$\int_0^1f(x){\rm d}x=[e^{-2x}(x+1)]_0^1=\frac{2}{e^2}-1.$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on this equality? I'm having trouble seeing where it comes from myself.

$$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}(u+t)}\int_x^0f(u){\rm d}(x-u)=\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}u}\int_0^xf(u){\rm d}(u)$$

Comment: which one? $d(u+t)=du$？

Comment: Never mind, I'm dumb. The multivariate nature of the integral and how you did the $u$-substitution just confused me, never seen it done quite that way.

Comment: Anyhow, everything *seems* correct to me, but I'd wait for confirmation from someone else just in case owing to my own slight confusion earlier (i.e. I might not be the best person to evaluate your answer, even if I agree).

Comment: @mengdie1982 Correct to me!

Comment: Correct ot me too !